# app.user not set when manually authentications a user

Tags: symfony

I'm following an example of how to manually authenticate a user after registration, it looks like this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user->getUsername(), null, 'main', array('ROLE_USER'));
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Bu because I'm using doctrine entity as a user provider, it's not being set correctly and I dont know how to do this right. If I pass $user as a first argument webpage loops indefinitely. I feel like there should be a DoctrineUserToken class somwhere but can;t find it.

Can you direct me please?

EDIT:

if I change the line to this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
```

where I pass $user as first argument, and get roles from user object, then a redirection results in a infinite loop.

I'm lost.

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle to handle logins? If no, why not?

Comment: Is your firewall definitely called 'main' in `security.yml`

Comment: @Kasheen, I confused firewall name with provider name. After putting correct firewall name issue was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @Leo, Interesting point actually. `UsernamePasswordToken` says `providerKey` as the third parameter, I've always used my firewall name however I've just noticed that both my firewall and user provider are both called `main`. I think it should indeed be the name of the firewall you wish to authenticate against though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user->getUsername(), null, 'secured_area', array('ROLE_USER'));
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

$providerKey must be get form secure.yml:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        form_login:
            check_path: /signInCheck
            login_path: /signIn
        logout: true
```